# What is the correct way to escape a string for a mailto link

Tags: php, html, url, encoding

I've got a `mailto:` link in a page here including `subject=` and `body=` parameters but I'm not sure on how to correctly escape the data in the parameters.

The page is encoded in `utf-8` so I guess all special chars like German umlauts should be encoded into `utf-8` representations for the URL too?

At the moment I'm using `rawurlencode()` as `urlencode()` would insert `+` characters in all locations where spaces should have been but I'm unsure if this is the correct way to do so.

Comment: I would have thought that either `rawurlencode()` or `urlencode()` should do the job - the browser should correctly decode either version before passing it to the mail client. You could also create an array of the parameters and use [`http_build_query()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php) - the query string is in the same format. Make sure you also pass the resulting string from any of those options through [`htmlspecialchars()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) if it is to be used in a HTML page...

Comment: Well it works like that in all usecases that i thought of, but maybe it's not the correct way to do this and my browsers/mail client just correctly recognize and work around that error, that's why is asked, just to be sure :)

Comment: There may be situations where one will work and the other won't, but if this is the case then it would be the fault of the browser for not interpreting it correctly. If there is a known bug with one or the other obviously it's best to avoid it, but I don't know of any modern browser that would make such a fundamental error - if there is one, it will probably be so poor as to be unusable anyway.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You just need to `rawurlencode()` the link at the end of the email address according the the W3C standards.

There is an example on the PHP Manual for urlencode (search for mailto on that page):
http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php

Comment: Please note that 'rawurlencode()' will escape ampersands to &amp;, which most mail clients won't properly decode. %26 should be used to replace these ampersands using something like a `str_replace('&amp;','%26',rawurlencode($subject))`

Comment: @dev_row with that str_replace code the `&amp;` will have been changed to `%26amp%3B`. You **first** need to replace `$amp;` with `&` and then do the rawurlencode(). Also why not use `htmlspecialchars_decode()` rather than the str_replace?

Comment: I have just added an answer that shows an example using this answer and comments: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46865401/1617737

Answer (score 8):

Based on the accepted answers and it's comments, this is what I have used:

```
function format_text_for_mailto_param($text) {
    return rawurlencode(htmlspecialchars_decode($text));
}
```

Example:

```
$email = "someone@example.org";
$subject = "Test Subject";
<a href="mailto:' . $email . '?subject=' . format_text_for_mailto_param($subject) . '">send email</a>
```

Comment: Don't you need to `return $text;` at the end of the function?

Answer (score 1):

```
function MailToUrl ($strUser, $strServer, $queryParams = null) {
    $strUrl = 'mailto:' . rawurlencode($strUser) . '@' . rawurlencode($strServer);
    if ($queryParams) {
        $strUrl .= '?' . http_build_query($queryParams, null, null, PHP_QUERY_RFC3986);
    }
    return $strUrl;
}

function MailToLink ($strUser, $strServer, $queryParams = null) {
    $strUrl = MailToUrl($strUser, $strServer, $queryParams);

    $strEscapedUrl = htmlspecialchars($strUrl);
    $strVisibleUrl =  htmlspecialchars(rawurldecode($strUrl));

    $strLink = "<a href='{$strEscapedUrl}'>{$strVisibleUrl}</a>";

    return $strLink;
}

print (MailToLink('"very.(),:;<>[]\".VERY.\"very@\ \"very\".unusual"', 'test.com', ['subject'=>'this & \ that / ']));
print (MailToLink('müller', 'test.com', ['subject'=>'Einflußgröße']));
```